# successive pointer casting in C

Tags: c, pointers

I am looking through some example code which employs an API to understand how to properly use the API. I came across some code which I found confusing. Below are the relevant chunks of code:

```
typedef struct myStruct_id{
randomStruct1 var1;
void *var2;
unsigned char *var3;
randomStruct2 var4;
int var5;
}myStruct_name;

//Function Prototype
void randomFunction(const randomStruct1 *in1, const randomStruct2 *in2, void *handle);

//Global Variables
//assuming data1-5 are of the correct types corresponding to randomStruct1, void, etc.
myStruct_name myStruct_var = {data1, data2, data3, data4, data5}; 
void *handle = (void*)myStruct_var; 

void main(){
    myStruct_name *local_var = (myStruct_name *)handle;
    //Other code here
    local_var.var2 = randomFunction(&local_var.var1, &local_var.var4, &(local_var));
}
```

My understanding is that the variable handle is a <strike>null</strike> *generic* pointer, pointing to the variable myStruct_var (which has been type cast as a <strike>null</strike> *generic* pointer). In the main function, the variable local_var is a pointer to the struct myStruct_name, pointing to the value of the pointer handle (which is type cast as a pointer to type myStruct_name) which is pointing to the variable myStruct_var. Next the function randomFunction takes as inputs a pointer just to var1, a pointer to just to var2, and a pointer to the variable local_var.

My confusion is this: the function randomFunction requires as input pointers pointing to structs and a <strike>null</strike> *generic* pointer. If local_var is already a pointer, why is the address operator (&) required? Is not the value of local_var already an address? Or is my understanding of what is going on with local_var incorrect?

Also, is there a reason why the final input to randomFunction is parenthetical? That is, why is it &(local_var) instead of just &local_var? Are the parenthesis doing something?

Thanks for reading and any responses!

EDIT: Thanks for the responses indicating I am not referring to a null pointer. I'm referring to the **void** "data type" here as generic.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: I think you want to read up the concept of a *null pointer* - Your usage of it sounds confused.

Comment: A _null pointer_ by definition points nowhere. Just being declared `void *` does not qualify a pointer as null pointer. Said that, why defy type-checking at all? Don't use `void *` or casts without true need.

Comment: Thank you for the responses about my incorrect reference to null pointers. The code I have posted is not my code but from an API. I removed the irrelevant code and re-wrote the variables, etc. more generically. At the core, my questions are about whether or not the code is unnecessarily complex or I lack the knowledge to understand the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your background is in Java or some other "safe" language, pointers can genuinely be very hard to wrap one's head around. But at the core you're just dealing with memory.

First question - Why address of pointer?

Here's some sample code you can play with. It tries to implement a "shallow" swap in two ways.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {int x; int y; int z;} XYZ;

XYZ s1 = {1, 2, 3};
XYZ s2 = {4, 5, 6};

void swap1(XYZ *a, XYZ *b);
void swap2(XYZ **a, XYZ **b);

int main()
{
    XYZ *p = &s1;
    XYZ *q = &s2;

    printf("Before\n");
    printf("Contents s1: %d %d %d s2: %d %d %d\n", s1.x, s1.y, s1.z, s2.x, s2.y, s2.z);
    printf("Contents p: %d %d %d q: %d %d %d\n", p->x, p->y, p->z, q->x, q->y, q->z);
    printf("Addresses: %p %p %p %p %p %p\n", &s1, &s2, p, q, &p, &q);

    swap1(p, q);

    printf("Swap 1\n");
    printf("Contents s1: %d %d %d s2: %d %d %d\n", s1.x, s1.y, s1.z, s2.x, s2.y, s2.z);
    printf("Contents p: %d %d %d q: %d %d %d\n", p->x, p->y, p->z, q->x, q->y, q->z);
    printf("Addresses: %p %p %p %p %p %p\n", &s1, &s2, p, q, &p, &q);

    swap2(&p, &q);

    printf("Swap 2\n");
    printf("Contents s1: %d %d %d s2: %d %d %d\n", s1.x, s1.y, s1.z, s2.x, s2.y, s2.z);
    printf("Contents p: %d %d %d q: %d %d %d\n", p->x, p->y, p->z, q->x, q->y, q->z);
    printf("Addresses: %p %p %p %p %p %p\n", &s1, &s2, p, q, &p, &q);

    return 0;
}

void swap1(XYZ *a, XYZ *b)
{
    XYZ *t;
    t = a;
    a = b;
    b = t;
}

void swap2(XYZ **a, XYZ **b)
{
    XYZ *t;
    t = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = t;
}
```

When you compile and run the above code, you'll get something like this:

```
Before                                                                                                                 
Contents s1: 1 2 3 s2: 4 5 6                                                                                           
Contents p: 1 2 3 q: 4 5 6                                                                                             
Addresses: 0x60103c 0x601048 0x60103c 0x601048 0x7ffd29c58288 0x7ffd29c58280                                           
Swap 1                                                                                                                 
Contents s1: 1 2 3 s2: 4 5 6                                                                                           
Contents p: 1 2 3 q: 4 5 6                                                                                             
Addresses: 0x60103c 0x601048 0x60103c 0x601048 0x7ffd29c58288 0x7ffd29c58280                                           
Swap 2                                                                                                                 
Contents s1: 1 2 3 s2: 4 5 6                                                                                           
Contents p: 4 5 6 q: 1 2 3                                                                                             
Addresses: 0x60103c 0x601048 0x601048 0x60103c 0x7ffd29c58288 0x7ffd29c58280
```

Note that swap 1 didn't do anything, it was only at swap 2, where addresses of the pointers were used, that a swap happened. Also note that `s1` and `s2` were left unaltered. You might use this function to implement a sort which doesn't need to copy entire structures.

Second question: Why `&(local_var)` vs. `&local_var`?

The differences are not functionally significant. It might have been a remnant of a previous expression, cut & paste, anything. Lots of reasons.

Comment: Thanks Yimin! Just to hammer home my understand. local_var IS a pointer and using the address operator (&) with local_var is passing the address of the associated local_var to the function randomFunction? Whatever the function is doing, it is being passed "address of a pointer" data?

Comment: That's right, `local_var` is a pointer to a structure, and `&local_var` is the address of the pointer to the structure.